# Shadow background when click on table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I made a table with custom cells. Every cell is a text field. I'd like that when I click on the random cell a shadow layer (transparent bockground) appears on the other unfocused cells as shown in the following picture link.

http://i47.tinypic.com/nwd45e.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have set your tableViewCell's background in your storyboard/xib to have the default color (which is basically clear to allow the tableView color to be what you want), then you can do something like the following.

```
// assume that the background color for the tableView in the storyboard is lightOrange,
// as seen in http://i47.tinypic.com/nwd45e.png

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    ... the normal code for getting your cell, probably involving DequeueReusableCell ...

    // yes, the following gets called for every row even when selection doesn't change,
    // but it is a very small hit.  could be replaced by overriding reloadData for the
    // tableView, but that isn't always desirable.
    if (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow)
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    else
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightOrangeColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    ... whatever else you would do for a selected row, perhaps a segue or something ...
    ... (and if part of this is to de-select a row that is already selected, take that ...
    ... into account as a conditional for the following line of code.

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: you probably need to change the color of the text as well with the background to achieve to effect in the picture.

Comment: @KDaker: agreed.  i considered briefly editing the answer to account for this, then realized how to change the text will be dependent upon the type of cell (title, title+description, custom).